# Python regex matching URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, url, python-re

I have a list in text file of URLs with some unwanted texts I have wrote a regex which will meet my needs and that is work fine but I am facing a problem where the regex add to the output unwanted samples [''] below the examples:

file content a list of URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/52                   (Status: 403) [Size: 919]
http://www.example.com/details              (Status: 403) [Size: 919]
http://www.example.com/h                    (Status: 403) [Size: 919]
http://www.example.com/affiliate            (Status: 403) [Size: 919]
http://www.example.com/56                   (Status: 403) [Size: 919]
```

the regex I used is: `"^[://.a-zA-Z0-9-_]*"`

the output as below:

```
['http://www.example.com/52']
['http://www.example.com/details']
['http://www.example.com/h']
['http://www.example.com/affiliate']
['http://www.example.com/56']
```

I need the output to be like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/52
http://www.example.com/details
http://www.example.com/h
http://www.example.com/affiliate
http://www.example.com/56
```

the code used for this program below:

```
import re

with open("test.txt","r") as test:
    for i in test:
        x = re.findall("^[://.a-zA-Z0-9-_]*",i)
        print(x)
```

Comment: Perhaps `print(x[0])` is what you are looking for.

Comment: that is working thank you j1-lee

Comment: Without using `regex` as well the same can be applied as `url = i.split()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findall` produces a list of strings, you can either print out the first element in the result `print(x[0])` or just use `match` instead for this use case since there is 1 url per line.

```
with open("test.txt","r") as test:
    for i in test:
        x = re.match(r"[://.a-zA-Z0-9-_]*", i)
        print(x.group(0))
```